# How to give condition in SwiftUI while using parent and child view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have custom view as below which i am using in another view

```
import SwiftUI

public struct TopSheet<Content >: View where Content : View {
    private var content: () -> Content
    
    @State private var arrowOffset: Double = 0
    
    public init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) { self.content = content }
    
    public func expandRatio() -> Double { return max((currentHeight - minHeight) / contentHeight, 0) }
    
    public var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center) {
            Arrow(offset: arrowOffset)
                .stroke(Color.pink, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 4, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                .frame(width: 30, height: 4)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

I am using above view in below view

```
import SwiftUI

struct PassengerView: View {
    
    @State private var passengers: [String] = ["Joe Black", "Eva Green", "Jared Leto"]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        TopSheet {
            VStack {
                ForEach($passengers, id: \.self) { passenger in
                    HStack {
                        Text(passenger.wrappedValue)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, .afklPaddingL)
        }
    }
}
```

Here I want to give one condition `Arrow()` from `Topsheet` should visible only if passenger count is greater than 1.

I am not sure how should i give this condition as both are in diff view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Add a var to your `TopSheet`:

```
var count: Int
```

Change the constructor to:

```
public init(count: Int, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
    self.count = count
    self.content = content
}
```

and your body to:

```
public var body: some View {
    HStack(alignment: .center) {
        if count > 1 {
            Arrow(offset: arrowOffset)
                .stroke(Color.pink, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 4, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                .frame(width: 30, height: 4)
        }
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

call it like:

```
TopSheet(count: passengers.count) {
            VStack {
........
```

As `passengers` is a `@State` variable it will reavaluate your views as it changes.